# Hi, I am trying Execute the following code in Visualforce page to get the current Location, But output is not coming. Please check & provide solution

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html5, geolocation, google-map

Link of the code:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Current-Location-Latitude-and-Longitude-using-JavaScript-and-HTML5.aspx

Code:

```
<apex:page>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: LatLng,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
} else {
    alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The best way to debug Javascript is to open the Google Chrome dev console and see the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Saumya Ranjan said, update the google map js to https `src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"` Or remove the protocol so that it will automatically take the browser protocol `src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"`. Both will work.

Another point I noticed, you have not handled your code in case the browser permission is denied. You should handle as below.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  console.log("Permission Granted");
},
function (error) { 
  if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
      alert("Permission Denied");
});
```

Updated code:

```
<apex:page>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: LatLng,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    },
    function (error) { 
        if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            alert("Location permission denied by user.");
        }
    });
} else {
    alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I tried , that above code. Sometimes it is not coming in Google chrome.                                                                                          now it is showing Error: ! oops something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. see javaScript console for technical details.

Comment: This is the standard way to implement the MAP API as provided by Google, there is nothing wrong with this code. I think this is related to API Key. Please check this link https://churchthemes.com/page-didnt-load-google-maps-correctly/

Answer (score 0):

Change the url to https ;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```

Otherwise it will block it as not-secured script.